# How do we optimize the lowest eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix using NMinimize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

I am trying to diagonalize the symmetric matrix while optimizing
the lowest eigenvalue subject to constraints.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; 

v={a,b,c,d,e};

A = {{a,     b - e, b + e},
     {b - e, c,     d},
     {b + e, d,     c}};

eigsys = Eigensystem[A];
evals = eigsys[[1]]; 
evect = eigsys[[2]];

order = Flatten[Map[Position[Sort[evals], #] &, evals]];
evalues = evals[[order]];
evectors = Normalize /@ evect[[order]];

m1 = evalues[[1]]; 
m2 = evalues[[2]];
 m3 = evalues[[3]];

m = m2^2 - m1^2;
 M = m3^2 - m1^2;
ssq13 = (evectors^2)[[3, 1]]; 
ssq12 = (evectors^2)[[2, 1]]/(1.0 - ssq13);
ssq23 = (evectors^2)[[3, 2]]/(1.0 - ssq13);

constraints = {m1 >= 0, m1 < m2 < m3, m1 + m2 + m3 <= 0.11,
-0.1<=a<=0.1, -0.1<=b<=0.1, -0.1<=c<=0.1, -0.1<=d<=0.1, -0.1<=e<=0.1,
   0.292 <= ssq12 <= 0.316, 0.02184 <= ssq13 <= 0.02308, 0.40 <= ssq23 <= 0.60,
   7.22 10^-5 <= m <= 7.63 10^-5, 2.483 10^-3 <= M <= 2.537 10^-3};

 sol1 = NMinimize[{m1, constraints}, v]
```

This code is giving the error message `NMinimize::bcons` that Constraints are invalid and constraints should be equalities, inequalites, or domain specifications on the variables. Is there any way that I can make it work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do the `constraints` mean? Maybe if you explain a bit what you are trying to achieve, especially concerning the constraints on the coefficients of the eigenvectors, you will get better answers.

Comment: I am unable to find any five numbers $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ that satisfy your `constraints`. Try this: `FindInstance[And @@ constraints, v, Reals]`, it seems to run forever without [finding an instance](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html).

Comment: My guess is, that the constraints involving "Root[...]" (for example m1, m2, ...) are too complicated for Mathematica. If you get rid of them and only use the constraints that directly involve a,b,c,d and e you get a solution. Maybe you find a way to turn the "Root[...]"-expressions into analytical expressions or try to find numerical solutions.

Comment: `Sort[evals]` does not do what you think it does. Because these are symbolic expressions, you can't just sort them from small to large.

Comment: Maybe [`ResourceFunction["SymbolicSort"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SymbolicSort) is of use to you

Comment: @SjoerdSmit even better, there isn’t a need for sorting because `Root` already sorts the roots and make them accessible by index. Plus, `Eigensystem` returns them in this same order. So it’s all good and pre-sorted.

Comment: I suspect one problem is that `ToRadicals@evals /. Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} -> RandomReal[0.1 {-1, 1}, 5]]` yields complex numbers.  Use `Re[]` on appropriate quantities, since the imaginary round-off errors should be zero. That should take care of the error message.

Comment: `Or @@ Table[And @@ constraints /. Thread[v -> RandomReal[0.1 {-1, 1}, 5]], {10000}]` returned `False`, which does not bode well for solving this problem. Do you know any feasible points (satisfying the constraints)?

Comment: Some comments on your `constraints`: (1) The sum of eigenvalues is equal to the trace, so `m1 + m2 + m3 == Tr[A] == a + 2 c`, and (2) $0\le m_1<m_2<m_3$ implies that $A$ is [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix), which can be [tested without calculating the eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2336530/632893). Hope this helps.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hi, FindMinimum is giving multiple local minima corresponding to different initial values. But I need global minimum. Is there any way I can modify the program to get it?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Hi, in the simplest case when e=0, I am getting global minimum. But after introducing e, it's not giving any solution. But FindMinimum is giving multiple minima for different initial values which is undesirable for us. We are seeking for a unique solution. Is there any other approach to this problem on Mathematica?

Comment: @Roman Constraints are experimental data.